# Merging contents of two lists based on a if-loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a minor problem while checking for elements in a list:
I have two files with contents something like this

```
file 1:        file2:
 47            358 47
 48            450 49
 49            56 50
```

I parsed both files into two lists and used the following code to check

```
for i in file_1:
   for j in file_2:
      j = j.split()
      if i == j[1]:
        x=' '.join(j)
        print >> write_in, x
```

I am now trying to get a "0" if the value of file_1 is not there in file_2 for example, value "48" is not there is file_2 so I need to get the output like (with only one space in between the two numbers) Also both the conditions should produce only one output file:

```
output_file:
  358 47
   0 48
  450 49
   56 50
```

I tried using the dictionary approach but I didn't quite get what I wanted (actually I don't know how to use dictionary in python correctly ;)). Any help will be great.

Comment: have you tried keeping else statement ? else x = '0'.join (j)

Comment: Are the numbers (in file1 and second number in file2) always in order? Alphabetical or Numerical order? Are they even always numbers? Does the output file need to be in order?

Answer (score 2):

```
r1=open('file1').read().split()
r2=open('file2').read().split()

d=dict(zip(r2[1::2],r2[::2]))

output='\n'.join(x in d and d[x]+' '+x or '0 '+x for x in r1)

open('output_file','wb').write(output)
```

Test

```
>>> file1='47\n48\n49\n50'
>>> file2='358 47\n450 49\n56 50'
>>>
>>> r1=file1.split()
>>> r2=file2.split()
>>>
>>> d=dict(zip(r2[1::2],r2[::2])) #
>>> d
{'47': '358', '50': '56', '49': '450'}
>>>
>>> print '\n'.join(x in d and d[x]+' '+x or '0 '+x for x in r1)
358 47
0 48
450 49
56 50
>>>
```

Comment: File objects don't have a split() method.  open('file1').read().split() maybe?

Comment: file1 doesn't have `50` in it

Comment: @gnibbler, according to OP's output file and his concept, there is , if 50 is not there, it should show 0 50 in his result.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your code quite easily:

```
for i in file_1:
    x = None
    for j in file_2:
        j = j.split()
        if i == j[1]:
            x = ' '.join(j)
    if x is None:
        x = ' '.join(['0', i])
```

Depending on your inputs, the whole task might be of course simplified even further. At the moment, your code is `0(n**2)` complexity.

Comment: Actually, it's O(N+M). You just need a sequential scan of each file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a readable solution using a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for k in file1:
    d[k] = 0
for line in file2:
    v, k = line.split()
    d[k] = v
for k in sorted(d):
    print d[k], k
```

Comment: initialising dict to a certain values is better done with `.fromkeys` classmethod.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
l1 = open('file1').read().split()
l2 = [line.split() for line in open('file2')]

for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
    if x not in y:
        print 0, x
    print ' '.join(y)
```

but if you follow your logic, the output should be

```
358 47
0 48
450 49
0 49
56 50
```

and not

```
358 47
0 48
450 49
56 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def file_process(filename1, filename2):

    # read first file with zeroes as values
    with open(filename1) as fp:
        adict= dict( (line.rstrip(), 0) for line in fp)

    # read second file as "value key"
    with open(filename2) as fp:
        adict.update(
            line.rstrip().partition(" ")[2::-2] # tricky, read notes
            for line in fp)
    for key in sorted(adict):
        yield adict[key], key

fp= open("output_file", "w")
fp.writelines("%s %s\n" % items for items in file_process("file1", "file2"))
fp.close()
```

str.partition(" ") returns a tuple of (pre-space, space, post-space). By slicing the tuple, starting at item 2 (post-space) and moving by a step of -2, we return a tuple of (post-space, pre-space), which are (key, value) for the dictionary that describes the solution.

PS Um :) I just noticed that my answer is essentially the same as Daniel Stutzbach's.